# MPDF dejavuserifcondensed.mtx.php No such file or directory

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

Can someone help me with this I am getting the following message when trying to use MPDF

include(/var/www/svn_data/skeletonapp/mpdf/ttfontdata/dejavuserifcondensed.mtx.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I have chmod'ed the correct files ttfontdata, tmp and graph_cache

It seems like the system has to generate the files but its not.

Thanks,

Ross.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that directory ttfontdata/ is not writable for the process under which the PHP code is running. MPDF needs to generate and write some files there.

Simplest solution is:

chmod 777 ttfontdata